# How to safely allow single argument templated constructor without using explicit?

Tags: c++

I have a `Value` class which I use for wrapping and converting basic types.

```cpp
class Value {
 public:
  template <typename T>
  Value(const T &value) : value_(StringMaker<T>(value)) {} // Not marked explicit

  // Example -> Convert to String
  std::string AsString() const;

  // Example -> Convert to Int
  int AsInt(bool *err_flag = nullptr);

 private:
  const std::string value_;

  // Helper method to convert values to a string
  template <typename T>
  std::string StringMaker(const T &value);
};
```

I have other classes which use the `Value` class e.g. the class `Foo`:

```cpp
struct Foo {
  explicit Foo(const Value &value) : bar(value) {}
  const Value bar;
};
```

With usage as follows:

```cpp
  // Normal use
  std::cout << "Value converted to \"std::string\": " << Value(100).AsString()
            << std::endl;

  // Normal use via Foo class
  std::cout << "Value converted to \"std::string\" via \"Foo\": "
            << Foo(100).bar.AsString() << std::endl;
```

and output:

```cpp
Value converted to "std::string": 100
Value converted to "std::string" via "Foo": 100
```

I would like to make use of a implicit constructor for `Value`, but with [cpplint](https://github.com/cpplint/cpplint) and [Cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) I get the warning:

> Single-parameter constructors should be marked explicit.  [runtime/explicit] [5]

If I add `explicit` to the `Value` constructor I get additional errors like:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Foo::Foo(int)’
             << Foo(100).bar.AsString() << std::endl;
```

*Thus*, is there a safe way to keep the static analysis tools happy and also use implicit conversion?

Here is a working [example](https://onecompiler.com/cpp/3x36fqsuk) with additional use-cases.

Comment: why is fixing the errors with the explicit conversion not an option? I mean there is a reason why those tools warn about implicit conversions, making them explicit is the safe way

Comment: To be honest, in this case I actually don't now how to fix it with explicit conversion. But if I can I would.

Comment: what is `Foo` ? The error seems to be about a different class not about `Value`

Comment: `Foo` is another class or function which takes a `Value` instance as a parameter. Also please visit the [example](https://onecompiler.com/cpp/3x36fqsuk) link I've added for the post for a working example.

Comment: implicit `Foo(100)`. explicit: `Foo(Value(100))` : https://godbolt.org/z/j7Yzcsq3q

Comment: sorry I missed it.

Comment: Oh yeah, I've done the Foo(Value(100)) before. But because I use the `Value` class a lot I removed explicit from the constructor. Thus, I cannot do explicit with only `Foo(100)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Thus, is there a safe way to keep the static analysis tools happy [...]

Yes, make the converting constructor `explicit` ;)

You can only disable or ignore the warning or make the constructor explicit. Though the warning exists for a reason, implicit conversions can be a source of confusion. Because `Value`s constructor is a template, you can pass any parameter to `Foo`s constructor too. Latest when you want to add a second constructor for `Foo` this can be confusing, for example:

```
struct Foo {
  explicit Foo(const Value &value) : bar(value) { /* do something */}
  explicit Foo(int x): bar(x) { /* do something else */}
  const Value bar;
};
```

Then `Foo(100)` suddenly calls a different constructor, which instead of `something` does `something else`. Hence I suggest to make contructor of `Value` explicit.

> Thus, I cannot do explicit with only Foo(100)

`explicit` means just that: You have to explicitly call the constructor. `Foo(100)` does not explicitly call `Value`s constructor, but `Foo(Value(100))` does. The sequence of conversions is exactly the same, but the code is more clear.

So instead of:

```
std::cout << Foo(100).bar.AsString() << std::endl;
```

write

```
std::cout << Foo(Value(100)).bar.AsString() << std::endl;
```

Alternatively, find a way to silence the warning. In rare cases implicit conversions are just right, but you need to be aware of the implications.